# Activate CI/CD in Gitlab Project with Terraform

Tags: gitlab, terraform, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, pipeline

im not very familiar with Gitlab CI/CD or Terraform yet but my goal is to create a Gitlab project with terraform that will run a pipeline ones everything is setup. For the pipeline i need to provide some environment variables.

If i want to create them in my terraform like:

```
# CONFIGURE GITLAB PROVIDER
terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "15.9.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "gitlab" {
  token    = var.gitlab_token
  base_url = var.gitlab_base_url
}

# ADD PROJECT OWNED BY USER
resource "gitlab_project" "example" {
  name                        = "example-project"
  description                 = "Example project created with Terraform"
}

# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
resource "gitlab_project_variable" "ARM_CLIENT_ID" {
  project           = gitlab_project.example.id
  key               = "ARM_CLIENT_ID"
  value             = var.azure_client_id
  protected         = false
  environment_scope = "*"
  masked            = true
  depends_on = [
    gitlab_project.example
  ]
}
```

everything is getting created except the ENV's:

```
│ Error: POST https://gitlab.***.de/api/v4/projects/8917/variables: 403 {message: 403 Forbidden}
│ 
│   with gitlab_project_variable.ARM_CLIENT_ID,
│   on gitlab_project.tf line 41, in resource "gitlab_project_variable" "ARM_CLIENT_ID":
│   41: resource "gitlab_project_variable" "ARM_CLIENT_ID" {
```

Im only able to create the ENVs for the CI/CD, if i go to the project after created and activate the CI/CD options manualy.

**So is there a option how to activate the CI/CD for the Gitlab Project with terraform?**

Comment: Did you try adding `builds_access_level` and set it to `private` or `default`?

Comment: I couldnt replicate your error. I used an access token with api scope and my project visibility was private, under my company group in gitlab.com. Can you double check your access token and maybe try with private project if you are using public to see if there is a difference?